# Program to reset USB ports

Tags: windows, usb

For some reason, my USB headphones stop working from time to time and I need to manually replug the USB connector of the headphones. I am looking for a program to reset a given USB port. If possible, it should be possible to disable and enable one of several USB ports at once (one reason being that it would help to find the USB port I want to reset as USB port names can sometimes be not entirely explicit).

Comment: What OS do you need it for?

Comment: I have the issue on Windows but I'm curious for Mac and Linux as well in case.

Comment: You can try to disable/enable the device directly from Windows'es device manager. For Linux, see [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/661/249743) (it's about Ubuntu but it should work on any distribution).

Answer (score 7):

You can use [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html):

- free and portable
- supports Windows
- can disable and enable one or several given USB ports at once just as if you were unplugging or plugging the USB cable manually:

[image]

- gives the date of the last time the USB device has been plugged, which can be handy (otherwise try to find my headphones in the above pictures!).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [devcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon) tool can do it for you. It can [perform Enable, Disable, Restart, Remove and other](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-general-commands) operations on any device by it's name.
This tool is part of [Windows Driver Kit](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit), but you can find it as separate file [in the Internet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/deploymentguys/2009/12/16/where-to-find-devcon-exe/).

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1002950/quick-method-to-install-devcon-exe for a fast and easy way to download `devcon`.